# More efficient way to collapse groups using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, performance, grouping

I have an 8000 row spreadsheet where we utilize grouping to organize it. I have some buttons with macros on the sheet to help with the expanding and collapsing of the groups. The code works, however, it is rather slow.

```
       With sht.Outline
            .ShowLevels RowLevels:=6
            .ShowLevels RowLevels:=5
            .ShowLevels RowLevels:=4
            .ShowLevels RowLevels:=3
            .ShowLevels RowLevels:=2
            .ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
        End With
```

*Note:* I do have `Application.ScreenUpdating` turned off during this process.

Is there a more efficient way to collapse or expand the rows than what I'm doing now?

Comment: Do you have volatile functions?

Comment: @Jeeped None that I am using within the sheet itself or within this macro. Some exist within other modules though.

Comment: Wouldn't `.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1` be completely equivalent and much faster already (i.e. each operation overwrites the previous, so just do the last one)? Also, try toggling off calculations and application events.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon it actually isn't. It doesn't collapse all the lower levels so if you expanded a level 1 group that had level 2+ below it, those would be expanded. I need each and every group collapsed.

Comment: Instead of using grouping to organise it, can't you just use a Table Slicer to filter it on demand? Much simpler.

Comment: @jeffreyweir Not sure if I could use Table Slicers in this case, regardless I'm too deep into the project to change it now (2 years in and about to launch next month). I'm just going through all the code re-evaluating it. The collapsing and expanding is the slowest process I have and speeding it up would be nice but isn't necessary.